# Separating spaced Numbers in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, input, output

Hello I am working on a small program to sort out numbers taken from a file. At the moment, my current conundrum is how to take in the numbers from the file as just integers one at a time or how to separate them from a string.

```
sample input: 

3 4 6 60 9 10 2 20  
56 11 18
34

output:
3 4 6 60 9 10 2 20 56 11 /*prints out the first 10 numbers taken in then sorts it*/
3 4 6 9 10 11 18 20 56 60 /* after first 10 it looks at the next input then sorts it again*/
4 6 9 10 11 18 20 34 56 60
void Sortingnums(char *nums,int firsttime)
{
    //holds counter and temporary number//
    int i, k, temp;
    //holds temporary c string//
    char* wordnum;
    //just take in the first ten numbers and that is it.
    if(firsttime == 0)
    {
        wordnum = strtok(nums," "); 
        numbers[0] = atoi(wordnum);
        //take in the first 10 numbers in the string//
        for(i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            wordnum = strtok(NULL," "); 
            numbers[i] = atoi(wordnum); //store the number//
        }
        // output the first 10 numbers//
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cout << numbers[i] << " " << endl;
        }
        firsttime++;
    }
    while(
```

under the samples is my sorting algorithm that takes in a cstring array and splits it into the the integers separated by spaces however a problem I came into was the fact that the first 10 numbers must be printed before.

How would I sort out the rest of the input? (The 1st line of input can have more than 10 numbers)

Comment: It may help if you tell us what programming language you are using. (And add a tag)

Comment: @AlexKrauss I edited it into the title

Comment: The `break;` in line#42 should have been a `continue;`.

Comment: So you're preloading 10 items, then (1) sort, (2) print, (3) remove the first item, (4) add a new item, else quite if EOF, and finally (5) goto (1) . Does *that* (poorly) describe the algorithm you're looking for?

Comment: I tried to attempt this out of curiosity and your second output doesn't make sense as I get 2 in the beginning.

Comment: If your assignment is unrestricted regarding standard library usage, you may find this a LOT easier to use it rather than reinventing al four wheels on your automobile. [See this sample](http://ideone.com/32AzOW) for such usage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to be basic and simple yet actually use C++ (and basic C functions).

1. read all the text in the file into std::string.
2. split the string by the delimiter '\n' (or "\r\n", depends on the input) into "std::vector lines". (using std::string::find(), std::string::substr()).
3. loop lines, and for each line split by the delimiter ' ' into "std::vector string_numbers".
4. loop "string_numbers" and use atoi() to insert each string_number into std::vector numbers.
5. sort (MANY algorithms on the net. bubble sort is pretty easy but not efficient O(n^2). If you are looking to implement yourself for something more efficient look at merge-sort O(nlogn) or quick-sort O(nlogn) in average case, harder to implement but MUCH faster).

Comment: Alright I have updated my question with my sorting function and a new question in it

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the Standard Template Library to help you control the numbers and sort. Also, I'm not sure where the numbers 2 and 3 went in your example output lines... I'm assuming that was a typo and you don't need to remove those numbers from the sorted vector for some reason.

Anyway, I'd do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

bool mySort(int i, int j) 
{ 
    return (i < j); 
}

void printVector(vector<int> &v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        cout << v[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;
}

void getNumbers(string &strNums)
{
    ifstream file("input.txt");
    string line;

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while (file.good())
        {
            getline(file, line);
            strNums += line + " ";
        }

        file.close();
    }
}

void sortAndPrintNumbers(char *input)
{
    vector<int> vNums, vNumsSorted;
    char * strNum = strtok(input, " ");

    if (strNum)
        vNums.push_back(atoi(strNum));

    while (strNum)
    {
        strNum = strtok(NULL, " ");

        if (strNum)
            vNums.push_back(atoi(strNum));
    }

    // Get first 10 numbers, print them, then sort.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && i < vNums.size(); i++)
        vNumsSorted.push_back(vNums[i]);

    printVector(vNumsSorted);
    sort(vNumsSorted.begin(), vNumsSorted.end(), mySort);

    for (int i = 10; i < vNums.size(); i++)
    {
        vNumsSorted.push_back(vNums[i]);
        sort(vNumsSorted.begin(), vNumsSorted.end(), mySort);
        printVector(vNumsSorted);   
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string strNums;

    getNumbers(strNums);

    char * pNums = new char[strNums.size() + 1];
    strcpy(pNums, strNums.c_str());

    sortAndPrintNumbers(pNums);
    delete [] pNums;
}
```

It's a little messy swapping between character arrays and strings, but I wasn't sure if you wanted to use Boost or just wanted to see the strtok solution. Also, you can specify the range of vector items you want to sort only, so a more elegant solution could utilize that.

Cheers